# I have a response from an API in the form of a binary file and I need to transform it into a PDF in react.js

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation, binaryfiles

I've been trying everything but I can't generate the PDF properly; either I get a blank PDF or a text file with gibberish characters.

`try {
const response = await getFunc(getUrl, token, header);

```
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));

  // Crear un enlace para descargar el PDF
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", "miArchivo.pdf"); // Cambiar a .pdf
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();

  // Limpieza después de la descarga
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  document.body.removeChild(link);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error al descargar el certificado:", error);
}`
```

I need the PDF file

By the way, this is how the API give me the PDF.

Postman View of the response: [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDDEJ.png)

Postman headers that came with the file: [Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2lMc.png)

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead...

```
try{

 let response = getFunc(getUrl, token, header);

 let blob=new Blob([response],{type:"application/pdf"});

 let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

 let link = document.createElement('a');

 link.target = '_blank';

 link.href = url;

 link.download='miArchivo.pdf';

 link.click();

 setTimeout(function(){URL.revokeObjectURL(url);},3000);

} catch(e){alert(e);}
```

**NB**: Script assumes your *getFunc()* which you haven't posted, works like a charm.

Comment: "I tried your code and it still generates a blank PDF, also on Postman I can download the file and it works.

Comment: Good man... you're fast! The error is probably in that function.

Comment: I'm going to simplify the API call. I'll let you know the result once I have it.

Comment: OK, good luck although I won't be here because I always use temp account! :)

Comment: Don't worry. By the way, it still doesn't work. But it's strange because on Postman, I can download it as a file, and it looks nice.

Comment: I have no idea what this postman is… but please use my code for the DL part because it’s better. Chao!